Writing real function as sum of complex exponentials
Consider a real function $f(x)$ that is at least $C^1$, I want to know what conditions one needs to impose on $f(x)$ to write it as,
$$ f(x) = C_0\left( e^{iA(x)} + e^{-iA(x)} \right )/2$$
where $A(x)$ is real. So essentially we have,
$$f(x) = C_0 \cos \left(( A(x)\right)$$
$$ \implies A(x) = \cos^{-1}\left(f(x)/C_0\right)$$
Which means that $f(x) \in [-C_0, C_0]$, so one restriction is that I need square-integrable functions such that $\int f(x)^2 dx < C_0$. Is this correct and do I need more restrictions?

As written, $f(x) =2C_0 \cos(A(x))$.  Now, what is the domain of $f$?

can it be the real line?

You have no question. You are asking what are the conditions on f so that $f(x)=C_0 cos(A(x))$. The condition is that $f(x)=C_0 cos(A(x))$. It’s like asking what condition on a function $g\in C^1$ do I need to impose so that $g=exp$. Well the condition is that $g=exp$.

Okay fair, so it just means that $|f(x)| < M$ for all $x$. Is that all?

Yes it is correct.
